# Reading KeyVault from Devopos Pipeline - YAML

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Adding task in yaml to read KV.

I got this yaml code:

```
parameters:
  - name: DeployTo
    type: string
    default: SIT
    values:
      - SIT
pool:
    vmImage: vs2017-win2016
variables:
    environmentToDeploy: ${{ lower(parameters.DeployTo)}}
    subscription: np
  
stages:
- stage: SIT
  displayName: SIT - Infrastructure deploy 
  condition: eq('${{ parameters.DeployTo}}','SIT')

  jobs:
     - template: ymlTemplates\environment-deploy.yml  # Template reference
       parameters:
          DeployTo: '${{ parameters.DeployTo }}'
          environmentToDeploy: '${{ variables.environmentToDeploy }}'
          subscriptionId: 'xxxf7fc0-exx3-x000-9f55-04xxxxxx76f4'
          SqlPassword: $(sqlpassword)
          AdminPassword: $(adminpassword)
```

Currently values for `sqlpassword` and `adminpassword` are being passed as pipeline variables.  I would like to read this from KeyVault.  How can i put a task in this .yaml before jobs. :)

Comment: I recommend that you first try using a service principal / service connection to avoid the whole KeyVault rigmarole. Obviously if this is an on prem SQL Server this is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AzureKeyVault task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops). The secrets from KeyVault will become available as pipeline variables.

The pipeline would look like this:

```yaml
  jobs:
     # assuming 'sqlpassword' and 'sqlpassword' secrets in keyvault
     - task: AzureKeyVault@1
       inputs:
         azureSubscription: 'my azure subscription'
         keyVaultName: 'my vault'
         secretsFilter: '*'

     - template: ymlTemplates\environment-deploy.yml  # Template reference
       parameters:
          DeployTo: '${{ parameters.DeployTo }}'
          environmentToDeploy: '${{ variables.environmentToDeploy }}'
          subscriptionId: 'xxxf7fc0-exx3-x000-9f55-04xxxxxx76f4'
          SqlPassword: $(sqlpassword)
          AdminPassword: $(adminpassword)
```

Comment: Keep in mind your service principle may have to have additional access to read Key Vault Secret values.